# Location Simulation not working in Xcode 10 and iOS 12

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am developing an app that uses GPS. In the simulator I always used the location simulation feature of Xcode which always worked for me.
I selected the Debug - Location - Freeway Drive option in Xcode 10.
Whenever I select some preset to simulate, Xcode shows the following error:

```
[Client] #Spi, Interrupted
```

GPS is enabled on the simulated device and the app has permission to access the GPS. I already tried to restart the simulator multiple times, selected another device, but no device works. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Regards

Comment: Have you tried deleting all your Derived Data (after closing the Simulator at 
~/Library/Developer/Xcode)?

I don't get that error but the GPS simulation is acting weird for me too with Xcode 10 + iOS 12 (didn't have anything like this before the update): 

it just stops working completely after a certain time without any warning, both on phone and watch btw.
The only thing I found so far is to delete all derived data, it is only a temporary fix though, at least in my case...

Comment: This did not solve the issue. I downloaded the latest Xcode Beta, started a simulator with iOS 12.1 Beta and it worked. When I switched back the latest Xcode release it also works there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Xcode 10 is broken with respect to Location Services in my experience. I've had to go back to 9.4 to develop and debug apps, but even then I have had problems with running apps originally modified with Xcode 10 running in iOS 12.

Apple is having serious, SERIOUS quality control issues and legacy issues with each new release of Xcode and iOS. I'm very frustrated and annoyed.

Comment: To be honest, Xcode 10 is very stable compared to previous versions. I now implemented my own location simulation (because it better suits my app anyways).

Answer (score 4):

I was having this issue and reseting the simulators seems to have fixed it for now:

```
$ xcrun simctl erase all
```

Comment: Worked for me also. This might need to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply click `City Bicycle Run` and then `City Run` in `Debug -> Location` in the Simulator over and over again until it works. At least it worked for me that way

Answer (score 1):

I'm suffering the same issue with Xcode 10.1 and iOS 12. Several restarts of the App and toggling between different locations (None, Apple, City Bicycle Ride) make it work again.

Quite annoying

Answer (score 1):

This worked intermittently as a workaround for me:

On the simulator debug menu, select location and freeway drive (or whatever you want) several times until it starts to track the location.

It also helps to build the app on the simulator again

Good luck!

Comment: This worked for me, after 3 hours of trying different things. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastico! Apple's got to fix this bug ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the location simulator has not been fixed in Xcode 10.1 update.

Comment: The issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

In the simulator, go into device settings / Privacy / Location Services. Toggle Location Services off and then back on.